# Problem with resource server when using Keycloak as an authorization server: "enc (use) is currently not supported"

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, keycloak, jwk

I'm trying to run the example from chapter 18 of the book *Spring Security in Action* (written by *Laurentiu Spilca*). It's about getting an access token from authorization server (here it is Keycloak) and then, operating on the resources that reside on a resource server (here it is implemented in Java using Spring Security). The problem is that any attempt to add fitness record leads to the following Internal Server Error:

```
{
    "error": "server_error",
    "error_description": "enc (use) is currently not supported."
}
```

**Description:**
The entire scenario is taking place on the same machine.
In Keycloak (15.0.2), I have defined a fitnessapp client (my application), assigned to it a Client Scope with the same name (fitnessapp). I have set its access tokens to have a lifespan of 100 minutes.
Then I define a user with username 'bill', assigning to it password '12345' within the Credentials section for user:
[image]
Then I define the role fitnessuser in the Roles section. From the Role Mappings section of the selected user, I assign fitnessuser.

 In order for book example to work properly, 3 additional properties need to be added to our JWT token: *audience, username and roles*

 As depicted below, I have done that using the Mappers section of fitnessapp Client Scope, using corresponding names for them from left to right:
[image]
As there were no problems in obtaining the access token from Keycloak, I just wrapped it up in the previous sentence and didn't explain more about this step.
This is the resource server configuration file that configures our `TokenStore` to use `JwtTokenStore`:

```
@Configuration  
@EnableResourceServer  
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)  
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {  
  
    @Value("${claim.aud}")  
    private String claimAud;  
  
    @Value("${jwkSetUri}")  
    private String urlJwk;  
  
    @Override  
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {  
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore());  
        resources.resourceId(claimAud);    
    }  
  
    @Bean  
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {  
        return new JwkTokenStore(urlJwk);  
    }  
  
    @Override  
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
        http.authorizeRequests()  
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").hasAuthority("fitnessadmin")  
                .anyRequest().authenticated();  
    }  
}
```

This is the application.properties file that separates the resource server port (9090) from Keycloak (8080), sets the expose endpoint for public key as well as the audience:

```
server.port=9090  
  
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/spring?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC  
spring.datasource.username=root  
spring.datasource.password=  
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always  
  
claim.aud=fitnessapp  
jwkSetUri=http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

Finally, the problem resides here in my POST request where it is meant to add fitness record to database but ends up in error:
[image]
**P.S.:** I have set a breakpoint in controller but it's never reached while debugging. So this problem is happening before even reaching the controller (probably in one of Spring Security filters). This is why I didn't see it necessary to provide any code from controller, service or repository here.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer directly your question, but you are using deprecated stuff. Have a look [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for very simple ways to configure resource-servers with latest boot versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that endpoint **/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs** will return to you 2 keys

- **use: sig** - responsible for token signature verification
- **use: enc** - responsible for encryption

The app is complaining because it can not understand the second one.
Since this is only book follow up and local development, you can navigate to **Realm Settings -> Keys -> Providers** inside Keycloak and remove provider that is responsible for **use: enc**.

I hope that the answer helps.

Comment: Thank you. That really helped. Just one question, since you mentioned that `this is only book followup and local development` before suggesting to remove the `use:enc`, what could be other alternatives to resolve this issue if suppose say this is in production?